# "parallel" planes?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Suppose you have two flat rectangular regions in $\mathbb R ^3$ such that if you expanded each into a plane, the planes would not intersect.  Would you say the regions are parallel?  Or is there a better word for this?

Comment: Yes, that is what I understand by "parallel planes" in $\mathbb R^3$.  Another way to say it: the two have the same normal direction.  Maybe instead of "the rectangles are parallel" I would say the rectangles lie in parallel planes".

Comment: @David Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Parallel is the correct term to define this situation and those region can be viewed also as subsets (i.e. contained) of two planes with parallel normal vectors.

Remember that the equation for a plane in 3d space is

$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$

and $\vec n=(a,b,c)$ is a normal vector to the plane.

Answer (score 1):

A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be defined as

$d=ax+by+cz$ where $(a,b,c)$ is the normal vector.  Remember the normal vector is perpendicular to the plane $P$.

If you have two planes, with normal vectors $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$, then you can tell if those planes are parallel if there exists a $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(a_1,b_1,c_1)= \lambda(a_2,b_2,c_2)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A plane is uniquely determined by a point on the space and a unitary vector, which is normal to the plane. We say that two planes are parallel if they don't intersect, this is equivalent as showing that their normal vector is the same (up to change of sign) and there exists at least one point that they do not have in common.